# Laravel view stored in subfolder can not extend layout template stored

Tags: php, laravel-9

I am trying to extend a layout stored in the layout folder into a subfolder. When i extend the layout into a file directly under the view folder it extends as usual, but when i try extending it into a subfolder under view. It just gives me the raw extend text. So in the page it will show as "@extend ('layouts.pickAlbum')" instead of the layout it self.

```
@extends('layouts.pickAlbum')
@section('sidebar')
@parent

@endsection

@section('content')
<h1>homePhotos page</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: "_It just gives me the raw extend text_" Most likely your file is not named `.blade.php` and doesn't get parsed by Blade

Comment: Nice, glad it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks forgot to add .blade into the file name, brombeer solved it.